# SharePoint column formatting - Condition on text that could be upper or lower case?

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list that has a column that is populated from a MS Form, the field that the user fills in is free text but they are required to enter a minimum of n/a into the box.  The formatting I am trying to get to work will change the background of the field red if the contents are not n/a.  As JSON is case sensitive I need to be able to check both n/a and N/A, I have found a reference to using (ToLowerCase) but my limited knowledge of JSON is not helping me here.

Current JSON

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "!=",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "n/a"
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50",
        ""
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "n/a"
              ]
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "n/a"
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below format.

[image]

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
                "class": "=if(toLowerCase(@currentField) != 'n/a', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50', '')"
            },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "n/a"
              ]              
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "n/a"
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  }
```